# Toilet leaking at lock nut

Tags: repair, toilet

today I installed a new Kohler Wellworth and new supply line. There’s a leak at the locknut where it meets the porcelain. I used a piece of cloth to make sure the leak is here and not the new supply line. When I was tightening the supply line (by hand and I’m not all that strong), I heard a loud snap and the tubing from the fill valve to the overflow had popped off. I can’t seem to get that back on, and I’m wondering what to do about the leak at the locknut. I don’t have the right wrench to tighten it but it feels tight when I try it with my hand. Do I have to replace the whole fill valve?

Comment: If it is leaking at the nut against the porcelain, then the seal inside is not sealing or the fill valve has a crack. The inside seal is where is where the water is held. Shut off the water at the valve and remove the supply line. Does it still leak? Flush the toilet to remove water, then remove the fill valve, carefully examine it, then reinstall.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn’t get the lock but off for the life of me so rather than spend a bunch of money on tools that various internet sources recommended, I hacksawed the bolt off and bought a new fill valve for 8 bucks. You were correct, obviously but whatever Hercules tightened that bolt obviously didn’t expect anyone to ever remove it! Thanks for the reply. I’ve never installed a toilet before. Off to do the next one upstairs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is leaking at the nut against the porcelain, then the seal inside is not sealing or the fill valve has a crack. The inside seal is where is where the water is held. Shut off the water at the valve and remove the supply line. Does it still leak? Flush the toilet to remove water, then remove the fill valve, carefully examine it, then reinstall.